# My laptop won't power on after an unexpected shutdown

Tags: battery, shutdown, hp-elitebook

I have an HP 6930 Elite book. I was just charging it in the afternoon yesterday while making a Word document on it and it suddenly got shutdown. No warning, no alert, no notification, just a sudden shutdown out of nowhere. And now, my laptop is apparently not even charging up. I have tried to switch it on with DC as well, no luck. I have already tried that "30 seconds press and hold power button" thing, that didn't work either. Please provide any possible solution to the problem.

**What I have already tried**

1. Unplugged the DC power supply for the whole night with the battery still connected.
2. Kept the power button pressed down for 30+ seconds with both, the AC and DC power supplies disconnected.
3. Tried powering the laptop on only with the DC power supply.

Comment: Disconnect AC, pull battery, connect AC, try powering on. Does it work?

Comment: Try leaving it unplugged for 30 minutes

Comment: @techie007 Nope, it didn't. That was the very first thing that I tried.

Comment: @Ramhound It was unplugged the whole time last night.

Comment: @Abbas Please edit your question to include ALL that you tried and what the results were.

Comment: @techie007 Alright, done that.

Comment: @Abbas | Why did it shut down?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams I have no idea at all. Like I mentioned in the question, it was just a sudden impact. I was only writing an article on MS Word while charging it and there were no other applications running either.